# Задача на сортировку столбцов матрицы

Tags: php

**Условия**: Есть квадратная матрица, заполненная числами от -10 до 10.

**Задача**: Преобразовать исходную матрицу таким образом, чтобы в рамках каждого столбца все отрицательные числа всегда находились ниже положительных чисел по вертикали, соблюдая при этом свой первоначальный порядок в отношении друг к другу.

[image: Пример]

```
<?php
function squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix) {
    $result = '<hr>';
    $squareMatrixSize = count($squareMatrix);
    for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
            $result .= $squareMatrix[$i][$j] . ' ';
        }
        $result .= '<br>';
    }
    return $result;
}
/*** Generate squareMatrix ***/
$squareMatrixSize = 10;
$squareMatrix = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
        $squareMatrix[$i][$j] = 10 - rand(0, 20);
    }
}
echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);
// TO DO:
echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);
?>

//на что хватило
    for($col = 0; $col < 10; $col++)
        usort($squareMatrix, $sort = function($a, $b) use ($col){

            if($a[$col] === $b[$col])
                return 0;

            return ($a[$col] < $b[$col]) ? 1 : -1;
        });
```

Comment: То есть сортируется каждый столбец независимо от других? Матрица здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Ну конечно, а как?

Comment: А где ваш вопрос?

Comment: @garjo_099 - Ну Вы бы хоть для приличия попробовали сами это сделать.

Comment: @garjo_099 - Пожалуйста, добавляйте код посредством редактирования вопроса, а не в комментариях. Спасибо. Что Вас не устраивает в приведенном коде?

Comment: array_filter - выбрать положительные, потом выбрать отрицательные, собрать вместе. исходный порядок при этом сохраняется

Answer (score 0):

Решение прям в лоб (неоптимизированное):

```
function squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix) {    
    $result = '<table>';
    $squareMatrixSize = count($squareMatrix);
    for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++) {
        $result .= '<tr>';
        for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
            $result .= '<td>';
            $result .= $squareMatrix[$i][$j] . ' ';
            $result .= '</td>';
        }

        $result .= '</tr>';
    }
    $result .= '</table>';
    $result .= '<hr>';
    return $result;
}
/*** Generate squareMatrix ***/
$squareMatrixSize = 10;
$squareMatrix = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
        $squareMatrix[$i][$j] = 10 - rand(0, 20);
    }
}
echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);

$arrSorted = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; ++$i) {
    $tmp = [];
    for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
        array_push($tmp,$squareMatrix[$j][$i]);

    }

    $plus = array_filter($tmp, function($var){
        return $var >= 0;
    });
    $minus = array_filter($tmp, function($var){
        return $var < 0;
    });

    array_push($arrSorted, array_merge($plus, $minus));
}

$squareMatrix = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; ++$i) {
    $tmp = [];
    for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
        array_push($tmp, $arrSorted[$j][$i]);

    }

    array_push($squareMatrix, $tmp);
}

echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x0dr-jbzy

---

UPD: Более лаконичное решение:

```
//********************************************
//  TODO 
$result = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++) {
    $col = array_column($squareMatrix, $i);

    $plus = array_filter($col, function($var){
        return $var >= 0;
    });
    $minus = array_filter($col, function($var){
        return $var < 0;
    });

    for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++) {
        $result[$j][$i] = $merge[$j];
    }   
}

echo squareMatrixToString($result);
//
//***********************************************
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vg6x-q9v5

Comment: Положительные должны сохранять порядок, у вас нет

Comment: @garjo_099 а ,я думал тоже сортировать по возрастанию надо....ну тогда закомментируй / удали строки `sort($plus, SORT_NUMERIC); $plus = array_values($plus);` и будет тебе счастье )))

Comment: не работает и так

Comment: @garjo_099 хочешь сказать вот это не работает: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g84f-z5vm  ???

Comment: @garjo_099 наверное я глубокой ночью был невнимателен когда читал вопрос..... подправил ответ и ссылки на тест. думаю теперь все работает как надо..... потому что ваш опубликованный ответ вроде тоже сейчас не соответствует вашему требованию)

Answer (score 0):

Пока что пришел к вот такому простому и лаконичному коду.

Рабочий код:

```
    /** Задача 3 */

    function squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix)
    {
        $result = '<hr><table style="text-align: center">';

        $squareMatrixSize = count($squareMatrix);

        for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++)
        {
            $result .= '<tr>';
            for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++)
            {
                $result .= '<td>'.$squareMatrix[$i][$j] . '</td>';
            }
            $result .= '</tr>';
        }

        return $result .= '</table>';
    }
    /*** Generate squareMatrix ***/

    $squareMatrixSize = 10;
    $squareMatrix = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $squareMatrixSize; $i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < $squareMatrixSize; $j++)
        {
            $rand = 10 - rand(0, 20);

            $squareMatrix[$i][$j] = $rand;

        }
    }





    echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);
    // TO DO:

    $tmp = [];

for($col = 0; $col < $squareMatrixSize; $col++)
{
    $plus = [];
    $minus = [];
    for($row = 0; $row < $squareMatrixSize; $row++)
    {
        $num = $squareMatrix[$row][$col];
        if($num >= 0)
            $plus[] = $num;
        else
            $minus[] = $num;
    }
    rsort($minus);

    $continueRow = count($plus);
    for($row = 0; $row < $continueRow; $row++)
        $squareMatrix[$row][$col] = array_shift($plus);


    $toEnd = count($minus);
    for($row = $continueRow; $row < $squareMatrixSize; $row++)
        $squareMatrix[$row][$col] = array_shift($minus);

}


echo squareMatrixToString($squareMatrix);
```

Comment: Даже как-то странно немного выглядит. Из моего кода не смог удалить нужные строчки, чтоб заработало, а свое что-то написал :-D

Comment: еще проще сделал - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/18y6-d4n9 :-)

Comment: я бы всё равно пока сам не сделал бы не успокоился, а Ваш код, не решал поставленную задачу и после удаления тех строчек которые Вы написали он вообще делал не то, что нужно. Спасибо за альтернативный вариант.

Comment: как так то? в каждом столбце положительные числа остаются в таком порядке как до сортировки, а отрицательные выстраиваются в порядке убывания непосредственно под положительными.. разве это не цель была? или просто тупо надо было расположить отрицательные под положительными, везде соблюдая изначальный порядок? щас могу подправить.. ведь ваш код тоже не соответствует тогда вашему же требованию)))